# How should I make a UI for my arduino project?

Tags: ui

It's easy enough to attach a display for displaying sensor data, but I'm wondering what the proper way is to have the user change variables using an user interface on the attached 2x16 display. 
The only library I found for this purpose:
https://liudr.wordpress.com/libraries/phi_prompt/

Takes a lot of code just to set up. I'm wondering if there's perhaps an easier option. All thoughts appreciated!

Comment: The key question is: what do you want to do? Sometimes developing an own library with exactly this functionality you need might be a good alternative to using a large all-in-one library from another party, especially for the Arduino boards with their limited resouces. In that case you also might learn a lot.

Comment: I'm just trying to change a few variables, call some functions, give the user the output of functions, etc. Of course I could reinvent the wheel but maybe there's some library I missed.

Comment: Well, in this case, reinventing the wheel would not be rocket science. I'd start simple.